# Python: Choosing C++ compiler on Windows -- MS Visual Studio to Mingw-w64. (PyStan CompileError)

Tags: python, c++, pystan

I'm getting a CompileError when running a simple PyStan model in Python:

> WARNING:pystan:MSVC compiler is not supported
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python36\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 423, in compile
>       self.spawn(args)   File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 542, in spawn
>       return super().spawn(cmd)   File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
>       spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)   File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 38, in spawn
>       _spawn_nt(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)   File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 81, in _spawn_nt
>       "command %r failed with exit status %d" % (cmd, rc)) distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe'
>   failed with exit status 1 During handling of the above exception,
>   another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\panormus\venv2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 3296, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 1, in 
>       sm = pystan.StanModel(model_code=model)   File "C:\panormus\venv2\lib\site-packages\pystan\model.py", line 349, in
>   **init**
>       build_extension.run()   File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
>       self.build_extensions()   File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in
>   build_extensions
>       self._build_extensions_serial()   File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in
>   _build_extensions_serial
>       self.build_extension(ext)   File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 533, in
>   build_extension
>       depends=ext.depends)   File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 425, in compile
>       raise CompileError(msg) distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 1

I've isntalled Pystan using pip (pip install PyStan) on Python 3.6 and am trying to run a simple model (first example [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-introduction-to-bayesian-inference-in-pystan-c27078e58d53))

I have both MS Visual Studio (not supported) and MinGW-64 (supported) installed on my PC. MinGW works fine to compile similar models using PyMC3, so it seems to me I just need to get my Pystan package to recognize the installation and use that compiler instead. Unfortunately even if that is correct, I am not sure how to do that, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself here. It turns out that others have had similar issues and that the 'standard solution' seems to be to run a conda virtual environment for all pystan modelling. The pystan docs have detailed installation instructions for conda, which worked for me, but no support for non-conda users.